# Nullstellensatz for Coordinate Ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that if E is an irreducible algebraic set, and given any ideal A $\in$ $k[x_1,..,x_n]/I(E)$, defining V(A) = {x $\in$ E st f(x)=0 $\forall$ f $\in$ A, one has {f $\in$ $k[x_1,..,x_n]/I(E)$ st f(x)=0 $\forall$ x $\in$ V(A)} = rad(A).

I know that an ideal in the quotient ring is radical iff its contraction is radical, so I'm trying to show that, if B is the contraction of A, I(V(B)) + I(E) = I(V(A)), however I'm stuck on how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the definitions in a rather straightforward manner, after realizing what's what.

A polynomial function $\bar{f}$ on $E$ can be treated as the coset $f+I(E)$ for some polynomial $f$. Then the function $\bar f$ has zero at a point $p \in E$ iff $f(p)=0$ (note that this does not depend on the choice of representative). It follows that $V(B)=V(A)$ (if one considers them as sets inside $\mathbb{A}^n$). Now, using the same observation/definition, We see that

- functions in $I(V(A))$ are all of the form $\bar f$, for $f \in I(V(B))$. That is, $I(V(B))/(I(E)) \supseteq I(V(A)),$
- on the other hand, whenever $f \in I(V(B)),$ then, trivially, $\bar f=f+I(E) \in I(V(A)).$ That is, $I(V(B))/(I(E)) = I(V(A)).$

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing why V(B) = V(A). V(B) is the set of all points in the ambient space killing everything in B, whereas V(A) is (effectively) the set of all points in E killing everything in B. Why can't V(B) then strictly contain V(A)?

Comment: @kfriend  Note that $B$ contains $I(E)$. Thus, if a point $p$ is killed by everything in $B$, in particular, it is killed by everything in $I(E)$, i.e. it is a point on $E$. From this the result follows.

Comment: Got it, thanks!